# Open Office PST on a Mac (Mac:Office)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office-for-mac, pst

I have a 5Gig Outlook PST file which I want to use on my Mac with Mac::Office but I don't want to import it into Outlook on the mac, I just want to read it. If I import it, it corrupts the outlook db due to its size :)

If this isn't possible, any ideas to view such a large amount of mail but keep it out of outlook?

thanks

Comment: Like David in his answer, I've not run into problems like this. Which version of Office for Mac are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into major problems reading PST files in Outlook 2011 for Mac, although they weren't related to the size of the PST.  Outlook for Mac mangled some of the header information (sender name, etc), screwed up the formatting, and made it impossible to export the emails - they wouldn't upload to an IMAP or Exchange server properly.  This was reproduced with several different PSTs from two different versions of Outlook for Windows.  In short, **I would never, under any circumstances use Outlook Mac to deal with PSTs if you care about the integrity of the data.**

My solution was to use a Windows VM and a trial version of Outlook 2010 for Windows to sync to a free IMAP email account.  Gmail worked decently although, believe it or not, I actually had the best experience with an Aol account.  Aol uses standard IMAP while Gmail's implementation is a little non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a "read only" program like [PST Viewer Pro](http://download.cnet.com/PST-Viewer-Pro/3000-2369_4-75219623.html)

You say it corrupts if you try and import it?

Any reason as to why ?

Ive dealt with some .pst much larger (15-18Gigs) and always been able to use them, although they do take a real long time to search and load.

Comment: It's for Windows, not Mac. I've tried it under wine, I've installed it, but it doesn't work.